# fire .change() when deselect a selected radiobutton

Tags: jquery

I wrote a function to deselect a selected radio button And a function to fire when change event made to the radio Button List.
This two function works.
But when I deselect a selected radio button, the ".change(function(){...})" doesn't fire.

Please Help.

Comment: You can't deselect a radio button, but if you wrote a function to do it, you have the trigger in the function itself, right?

Answer (score 1):

you can trigger any event to fire on any element like this:

```
$('#myId').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by doing:

`$('#id').on('click' function(){
    ...
});`

Answer (score 0):

According to [Jquery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/change/) you can trigger change event by calling the `.change()` method.

```
$('#myId').change();
```